# Accessing pgr_Dijkstra return values, including aggregated cost

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have the following pgr_Dijkstra SQL code for determining the shortest path between two points on a directed water stream network.  The results of the query don't give the total_cost or aggregated cost (agg_cost).  I know this is one of the outputs of the pgr_Dijkstra command, but just can't seem to make it return the -1 edge without an error.

```
ALTER TABLE streams ADD COLUMN length float8; -- add length field for pgr cost
ALTER TABLE streams ADD COLUMN cost float8; -- add cost column
ALTER TABLE streams ADD COLUMN reverse_cost float8; -- add reverse_cost column
UPDATE streams SET length = ST_Length(geom::geography);

-- create cost and reverse costs for stream network based on fldir field
UPDATE streams
SET cost = length(geom::geography) 
WHERE fldir IN (20,32,34); -- not identified(both direction), flow direction and the digitizing direction are the same, and not applicable values

UPDATE streams
SET cost = 1000000
WHERE fldir = 33; -- The flow direction and the digitizing direction are opposite.

UPDATE streams
SET reverse_cost = length(geom::geography)
WHERE fldir IN (20, 34, 33);

UPDATE streams
SET reverse_cost= 1000000
WHERE fldir =32;

WITH all_pairs AS (
  -- all pairs of start and end geometries with IDs
  -- that get carried through so the routing results
  -- match with the pt IDs you know.
  SELECT f.gid AS fid, f.geom as fgeom,
         t.gid as tid, t.geom as tgeom
    FROM from_pts AS f,
         to_pts AS t
), vertices AS (
SELECT fid, tid,
       (SELECT id -- proximity search for closest from vertex
          FROM streams_vertices_pgr
         ORDER BY the_geom <-> fgeom
         LIMIT 1) as fv,
       (SELECT id -- proximity search for closest to vertex
          FROM streams_vertices_pgr
         ORDER BY the_geom <-> tgeom
         LIMIT 1) as tv
  FROM all_pairs
)
SELECT fid, tid, agg_cost, pgr_Dijkstra(   -- added agg_cost, but error is produced.
  'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost, reverse_cost FROM streams',
  fv, tv, 
  directed := true
) from vertices;
```

The results of the query are as follows:

[image: pgr_Dijkstra Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field that you are trying to access, agg_cost, is one of the columns returned from the pgr_Dijkstra algorithm.  As shown in the table in your question, all the values returned from Dijkstra (wrapped in parentheses) are returned in a composite type. You need to unpack those.

To do this, let's add another `WITH` clause, containing the final query you show above and then an unpacking query. The algorithm results are in a column called pgr_dijkstra. You can pull just the agg_cost out of that as `(pgr_dijkstra).agg_cost` and it would be returned as a separate column. To get all fields in the composite type, you can use `(pgr_dijkstra).*` and each field in the composite type will be returned as it's own column. Putting this together:

```
WITH all_pairs AS (
  -- all pairs of start and end geometries with IDs
  -- that get carried through so the routing results
  -- match with the pt IDs you know.
  SELECT f.gid AS fid, f.geom as fgeom,
         t.gid as tid, t.geom as tgeom
    FROM from_pts AS f,
         to_pts AS t
), vertices AS (
  SELECT fid, tid,
       (SELECT id -- proximity search for closest from vertex
          FROM streams_vertices_pgr
         ORDER BY the_geom <-> fgeom
         LIMIT 1) as fv,
       (SELECT id -- proximity search for closest to vertex
          FROM streams_vertices_pgr
         ORDER BY the_geom <-> tgeom
         LIMIT 1) as tv
  FROM all_pairs
), pgr_result AS (
  SELECT fid, tid, pgr_Dijkstra(
    'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost, reverse_cost FROM streams',
    fv, tv, 
    directed := true
  ) from vertices
)
SELECT fid, tid, (pgr_dijkstra).* FROM pgr_result;
```

With the composite unpacked, you will be able to select just the final agg_cost  by adding `WHERE (pgr_dijkstra).edge = -1` if you only need that.

Comment: I am sorry that I am not catching on, but I am unsure how to send the query into a new table.  The code confuses me because I don't understand the last lines.  I don't know where to put the INTO pgr_result FROM command.

Comment: @MJM Okay, rather than suggesting how to do it, I expanded my answer to include the extra WITH clause and unpack the composite type in an extra SELECT.

Comment: It works amazing.  I added some sql statements and it produces everything I need.  Thank you.

Comment: you really helped me out.  Please go to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426935/inconsistent-qneat3-od-matrix-mn-layers-as-lines-results and I will award the bounty to you.  This didn't answer my QNEAT3 question, but it is a far better solution.